# Add Duration field to sort criteria programatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Can someone please tell me how to add duration(CCK field) to sort criteria of views programmatically because it is not listed there by default?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you mean by "duration"? What have you tried? What is your expected output?

Comment: duration is a cck field type http://drupal.org/project/duration and i have just tried making a view which can be sorted by this duration field. output should be the view block sorted by duration field. In my case duration is a time entered by the user took him/her to complete a challenge, so i want to sort their timings to get the top 10 participants of the challenge. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If no handler/field is provided in Views you have to refer to the API and write the views plugins to enable what you want to sort by.

http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/index.html

http://drupal.org/node/235062